# $f$ is increasing implies $Mf$ is increasing ???

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

For a given function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $, Hardy–Littlewood maximal function of $f$ defined by $$Mf(x)=\sup_{r>0}\frac{1}{2r}\int\chi_{[x-r,x+r]}|f|~d\lambda=\sup_{r>0}\frac{1}{2r}\int^{x+r}_{x-r}|f|~d\lambda$$ where $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue.

Is it ture that if $f$ is increasing then $Mf$ is also increasing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because of the absolute values. Say $f = -2$ on $(-\infty,0]$ and $f = 0$ on $(0,\infty)$. Then $Mf(-1) = 2$ while $Mf(1) = 0$.

However, if $f$ is non-negative, then the result is true: If $y < x$, then for each $r > 0$, $\frac{1}{2r}\int_{y-r}^{y+r} f(t)dt \le \frac{1}{2r}\int_{x-r}^{x+r} f(t)dt$. Now $\sup_{r > 0}$ both sides.

Comment: If $f$ is non-negative and strictly increasing, can I guarantee that $Mf$ is also strictly increasing? The proof above only shows that it is non-decreasing

Comment: @suncup224 yes; you can minorly alter the above proof to show strictly increasing

Comment: How so? I could now show $\frac{1}{2r}\int_{y-r}^{y+r} f(t)dt < \frac{1}{2r}\int_{x-r}^{x+r} f(t)dt$ but after taking the sup on both sides, the $<$ will become $\le$

Comment: @suncup224 there's some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $f(t) > f(t')+\epsilon$ for $t \in [x-r,x+r], t' \in [y-r,yr]$, provided $r$ is small enough.

Comment: Yes, but what if a large $r$ is where the supremiums are "achieved"? In other words, I can prove $\frac{1}{2r}\int_{y-r}^{y+r} f(t)dt$ and $\frac{1}{2r}\int_{x-r}^{x+r} f(t)dt$ have a definite gap for sufficiently small $r$ values but this may not be the case for big $r$ values and I do need to consider all $r>0$ when taking the sup. (Also the sups need not be "achieved" with the same $r$ values) Not sure if I'm missing something here!

Comment: I'm wondering if a function with a shape like $f(x)=arctan(x) + \pi/2$ will have $Mf(x) \equiv \pi/2$ for $x<0$

Comment: ^I just did direct computation. Let $A_x(r) :=\frac{1}{2r} \int \limits_{x-r}^{x+r} \arctan(u) + \pi/2 \ du$ Then $\frac{dA_x}{dr} = \frac{1}{2r^2} (x \arctan(x-r) - x\arctan(x+r) + 0.5 \ln \frac{1+(x+r)^2}{1+(x-r)^2})$ which is positive for all $x<0$ and $r>0$. So when $x<0$, $\sup\limits_{r>0} A_x(r) = \lim\limits_{r\to\infty} A_x(r) = \pi/2$

Comment: @suncup224 Oh yes, it's a sup.

Comment: @mathworker21 one doubt regarding your answer: Why is $Mf(1)=0$? Suppose, I take $r=5$, then $\frac{1}{10}\int_{1-5}^{1+5}|f|=\frac{1}{10}(\int_{-4}^0 2+\int_0^6 0)=8/10$. In fact, for $r \to \infty$, the above gives us $Mf(1)=1=\lim_{r \to \infty} 1-1/r$. Perhaps I'm getting something wrong. Although it proves the main point that $M$ is not increasing, regardless of the value.

Comment: @SubhasisBiswas no, you're right. good catch. ill fix the answer soon.