# Proving that if $f$ is nonnegative and increasing, then the maximal function of $f$ is also increasing.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, monotone-functions

The answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2993290/f-is-increasing-implies-mf-is-increasing) question suggests that if a function $f$ is nonnegative and increasing, then the Hardy–Littlewood maximal function of $f$ is also increasing.

> The maximal function is defined as
> $$Mf(x)=\sup_{r>0}\frac{1}{2r}\int^{x+r}_{x-r}|f|~d\lambda$$ where $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue.

The proof that the said answer provides is extremely intuitive and brief. Essentially, it is based on the assertion that if $y < x$, then for each $r > 0$,

$$\int_{y-r}^{y+r} f(t)\; dt \le \int_{x-r}^{x+r} f(t)\; dt \qquad(*)$$

Of course, $(*)$ is obvious in the case of Riemann integrals, but I am interested in rigorously proving $(*)$ since the integration is w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure. How can $(*)$ be proved given the hypothesis that $f$ is a nonnegative increasing function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what this has to do with differences between Riemann integration and Lebesgue integration. In either case you can rewrite the inequality as
$$\int_{x-r}^{x+r} [f(t) - f(t-(x-y))] \, dt \ge 0$$
and note that the integrand is nonnegative.

Comment: Could you please explain how the inequality in my question can be written as $\int_{x-r}^{x+r} [f(t) - f(t-(x-y))] \, dt$?

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson Sorry, I forgot the "$\ge 0$" part of the inequality; see my edit. The key is to note that $\int_{y-r}^{y+r} f(t) \, dt = \int_{x-r}^{x+r} f(t-(x-y)) \, dt$.